# Cannot find graphics drivers for Intel GM945, OpenGL Error

Tags: drivers

I am very new to Linux. I have been using Linux for only two days now and I am really impressed by Ubuntu. But I am facing a major problem. My PC is a Lenovo 3000 y500. My GPU is an Intel 945GM (integrated graphics) and I don't have any drivers for it because I can't find them. Someone please help me, I really can't wait to play my favorite games anymore.

When I run a game I get this error:

```
Could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'!
Either your video card is unsupported, or your OpenGL driver needs to be updated.
```

When I type `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`
I get the following result:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS,
943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03) 
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3801
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: Is there no way to run games on Linux because I could run them on windows?

Comment: Why do you undo formatting edits? Don't you see that it is unreadable now?

Comment: Well, I highly appologize  for my formatting edits.  Yes, I made it unreadable but now it has been fixed by a good person and this is exactely what I mean. I am sorry for my formatting edits once again.